# swift call did select button at index path.row within didselectItem

Tags: swift, xcode

is it possible to call something like did select row 
Button1(messageContact) or button2(sendFriendRequest)

And then have it do two seperate functions depending on which button you clicked within side the same cell for row ?

Ben

Answer (score 1):

You can make a delegate for your cell's actions:

```
protocol UserCellDelegate: class {
    func didTapSendMessage(_ sender: UserCell)
    func didTapAddSendFriendRequest(_ sender: UserCell)
}
```

and add this line at your UserCell:

```
var delegate: UserCellDelegate?
```

So when ever user tap on sendFriendRequest or messageContact, you do this:

```
@IBAction func sendMessageTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapSendMessage(self)
}

@IBAction func sendMessageTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapSendRequest(self)
}
```

And than confirm to that delegate from your view controller:

```
class UserViewController: UserCellDelegate {
        func didTapSendMessage(_ sender: UserCell) {
            guard let tappedIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: sender),
                let user = users[tappedIndex.section].content[tappedIndex.row] as? User else {
                    return
            }
            //Do what you need in order to send message to user
        }

        func didTapAddSendFriendRequest(_ sender: UserCell) {
            guard let tappedIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: sender),
                let user = users[tappedIndex.section].content[tappedIndex.row] as? User else {
                    return
            }
            //Do what you need in order to send friend request
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to set yourself as the cell's delegate:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = ...
        cell.delegate = self
}
```